# How to create and use an iOS Framework for sharing code with Extensions

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios8, ios-app-extension

How does the minimal setup and usage of a custom iOS framework look like? I starting to look into this in order to share code with a Today Extension.

Here's what I did so far

1. Added a new Target choosing the **Cocoa Touch Framework** template and called it *TesterKit*
2. Inside the framework I created a new class *TestClass.swift*
3. Inside *TestClass.swift* I created a simple class method *class fund tester()* printing a string for testing

Looking at my app I can see that TesterKit has been added as **Embedded Binaries** and **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**, however it is *red*

4. In order to use this new Framework in the app, I added *import TesterKit* to the top of my AppDelegate
5. Then I tried to call the class method from the Framework using *TestClass.tester()*. But instead of showing the log message I get a …

   "Use of unresolved identifier"

→ What am I doing wrong? Any wrong assumptions here?

Note: I already watched the WWDC sessions 416 "Building Modern Frameworks" and found the [Framework Programmign Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000183-SW1). If there are any example projects showing how to use such new custom iOS Frameworks, ideally using Swift + integrating this with Today Extensions, that might be helpful, too.

Comment: Have you watched the WWDC videos?

Comment: Red just means it doesn't exist - because it's being built by a different scheme. You need a Copy Files build phase that copies the framework, and it must target the Shared Frameworks destination.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like your import is not failing which means the framework is actually set up correctly...try making the function **public**.

```
public func tester() { print("tester()" }
```